# My discord bot is ignoring commands that have capital letters in them

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to put together a bot, and I've found that for whatever reason, it doesn't respond to any commands that have capital letters in them. And by that I mean it has defined commands that have capital letters in them, but the bot won't actually run the code in the commands that have capital letters. I have my commands defined in a switch/case that I've entered below, which uses properties of an object passed to the commands file from the main file.

```
switch (command.call) {
  case 'ping':
    message.reply(`Pong! This message had a latency of ${latency}ms.`);
  console.log(`Received message $ping, responded with latency of ${latency}ms.`);
    break;

  case 'help':
    message.reply('Current commands available:\n  \`$ping\`: Get the latency of the bot.\n  \`$help\`: Show this message.\n  \`$setPrefix\` \`[arg]\`: Set the prefix to a given string, \`[arg]\`');
    console.log(`Received message $help, responded with latency of ${latency}ms.`);
    break;

  case 'setPrefix':
    message.reply(`Set the new prefix to ${config.prefix}`);
    console.log(`Received message $setPrefix, responded with latency of ${latency}ms.`);
    break;

  case 'Test':
    message.reply('I got your message!');
  console.log(`Received message $test, responded with latency of ${latency}ms.`);
    break;
  }
}
```

So the commands `ping` and `help` work correctly, but the bot doesn't do anything when I try to call `setPrefix` or `Test`.

This is my code that passes the command to the file that defines the commands:

```
  commandBody = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length), //Get the body of the command
  args = commandBody.split(' '), //Get the command arguments
  call = args.shift().toLowerCase() //Get the command

  const command = {
    commandBody: commandBody,
    args: args,
    call: call
  }

  commands(command, message); //Call the given command from commands.js
```

That last line that calls commands() is referencing the file that defines the commands for the bot

Comment: `.toLowerCase()` what do you think this does?

Comment: I want to have the command be that case-sensitive text, which is why I'm asking. If I wanted everything to be lowercase, I wouldn't have a problem with this

Comment: `call = args.shift().toLowerCase() //Get the command`

Comment: oh, I didn't see that aaaaaaa

I got that bit of code off of a random tutorial, so ofc I didn't realize. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

Add to your code `.toLowerCase()`